# String incremental concatenation in a for-loop ignores "0" for some reason

Tags: javascript, for-loop, string-concatenation

I'm writing a function to get a number string from a string`, which works like this:

- For each character in the string, checks if it's a digit from `0` to `9`
- If it is, includes it in a new string
- Continues until the end of the string. If the string is `a0b109mmn5`, the function should return `01095`.

```
function stringToDigit(string) {
    if (string.length == 1) {
        switch (string) {
            case "0":
                return 0;
            case "０":
                return 0;
            case "1":
                return 1;
            case "１":
                return 1;
            case "2":
                return 2;
            case "２":
                return 2;
            case "3":
                return 3;
            case "３":
                return 3;
            case "4":
                return 4;
            case "４":
                return 4;
            case "5":
                return 5;
            case "５":
                return 5;
            case "6":
                return 6;
            case "６":
                return 6;
            case "7":
                return 7;
            case "７":
                return 7;
            case "8":
                return 8;
            case "８":
                return 8;
            case "9":
                return 9;
            case "９":
                return 9;
        }
    }
}
function stringToNum(string) {
    var numString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (stringToDigit(string[i])) numString += string[i];
    }
    return numString;
}
// $.writeln(stringToDigit("0"));
// $.writeln(stringToNum("000"));
console.log(stringToDigit("0")); // gets 0, good
console.log(stringToDigit("00")); // gets undefined, good
console.log(stringToDigit("a")); // gets undefined, good
console.log(stringToNum("a000b1c2d3e4f5g6h7i8j9")); // gets 123456789, not 000123456789, NOT GOOD!
```

However, for some reason, I can't include "0" in the result. I've tried both Visual Studio Code (with an console add-on whose name I forgot) and Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit CC, so I wonder if this is just how JavaScript works.

Comment: You have an `if` statement with the `stringToDigit(string[i])` condition, `0` is a **falsy** value.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I need the function to work with fullwidth numbers (used in East Asian languages) too, which cannot simply be gotten from strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (stringToDigit(string[i]))`  - is like `if(0)` where `0` is cast to `false`. Use `if (stringToDigit(string[i]) !== null)` instead.

`if` statement uses `==` (not `===`) by default. Therefore we have some conversions like:

- `null` to `false`, and
- `0` to `false`.

Note that in some cases you should check to `undefined`. In your case there is no default value, so either add `null` as default or check to undefined: `if (stringToDigit(string[i]) !== undefined)`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know 0 was falsy! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

While Alex answers perfectly to your question, I had a few minutes and did a little refactoring to what I would have used if I had to achieve your task.

```
function stringToNum(str) {
  // Object with all the string numbers and their digit equivalent
  var replacements = {
    "0": 0,
    "０": 0,
    "1": 1,
    "１": 1,
    "2": 2,
    "２": 2,
    "3": 3,
    "３": 3,
    "4": 4,
    "４": 4,
    "5": 5,
    "５": 5,
    "6": 6,
    "６": 6,
    "7": 7,
    "７": 7,
    "8": 8,
    "８": 8,
    "9": 9,
    "９": 9,
  };

  var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(replacements).join("|"),"gi");

  // Do all the replacements on characters matching object keys
  return str.replace(re, function(matched){
    return replacements[matched];
  })
  // Remove all the characters that are not a digit
  .replace(/\D+/g, '');
}
console.log(stringToNum("a000b1c2d3e4f5g6h7i8j9"));
```

This way should be faster and avoid the falsy 0 trap.

Here the [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/faxebet/edit?js,console)